# Toast stop working/showing after updated the gradle version to 3.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-toast

I have updated the `Gradle` version from **2.3.3** to **3.0.1**
and also updated the `JAVA` Version from **1.7** to **1.8**
Toast which were working perfectly fine before, it stops showing now

the code which I am using in the project

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Test case **`Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`**

Comment: tried it but not worked

Comment: add some more code.

Comment: I have not changed anything in the code
just updated the gradle to 3.0.1 and JAVA version to 1.8

Comment: try this one  `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()`; .

Comment: why `getBaseContext()` @Dharmishtha

Comment: Have you tried @AhmadArslan ?

Comment: @Dharmishtha No its not working

Comment: @AhmadArslan please check that in **Settings-> Application -> Manager**  check notification is on. if by accidentally you have set it off then also it affect Toast.

Comment: @Dharmishtha oh My god What I did :(  thanks for the help it works now

Comment: Should I delete this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check that in **Settings-> Application -> Manager** check notification is on. if by accidentally you have set it off then also it affect Toast.